Best practices for consuming an API and testing it
I am developing a microservice which integrates with a weather API. This is what the service looks like:
namespace WeatherService.Services;

using System.Text.Json;

public class WeatherService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _apiKey;

    public WeatherService()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        
        _apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_apiKey))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("API key not found in environment variable.");
        }
    }

    public async Task<WeatherData> GetWeatherDataAsync(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        if (latitude is < -90 or > 90)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(latitude), "Latitude must be between -90 and 90 degrees.");

        if (longitude is < -180 or > 180)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(longitude), "Longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees.");

        var apiUrl = $"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}&appid={_apiKey}";

        using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
        
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Failed to retrieve weather data. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var weatherData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherData>(responseData);

        return weatherData;
    }
}

This is the controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WeatherService.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Services.WeatherService _weatherService;

    public WeatherController(Services.WeatherService weatherService)
    {
        _weatherService = weatherService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(weatherService));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<WeatherData>> GetWeather(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        try
        {
            var weatherData = await _weatherService.GetWeatherDataAsync(latitude, longitude);
            return Ok(weatherData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

How would I test the service? Should I pass the API client into WeatherService instead so I can mock it in the tests. Or can I mock it the way it is? I am also going to add more endpoints to convert to different units of measurement too.
This is the idea I have for the tests but I'm hoping to not pass in the httpclient:
using Xunit;
using Moq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WeatherService.Services;

namespace WeatherService.Tests
{
    public class WeatherServiceTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetWeatherDataAsync_ValidCoordinates_ReturnsWeatherData()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockHttpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
            var apiKey = "fakeApiKey";
            var latitude = 40.7128;
            var longitude = -74.0060;
            var expectedUrl = $"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}&appid={apiKey}";
            var responseData = "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-74.006,\"lat\":40.7128},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":287.73,\"feels_like\":286.94,\"temp_min\":285.37,\"temp_max\":289.71,\"pressure\":1014,\"humidity\":65},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":0.89,\"deg\":45,\"gust\":1.34},\"clouds\":{\"all\":1},\"dt\":1635155175,\"sys\":{\"type\":2,\"id\":2039034,\"country\":\"US\",\"sunrise\":1635142372,\"sunset\":1635180205},\"timezone\":-14400,\"id\":5128581,\"name\":\"New York\",\"cod\":200}";
            var expectedWeatherData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherData>(responseData);

            mockHttpClient.Setup(client => client.GetAsync(expectedUrl))
                          .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                          {
                              Content = new StringContent(responseData)
                          });

            var weatherService = new Services.WeatherService(mockHttpClient.Object);

            // Act
            var result = await weatherService.GetWeatherDataAsync(latitude, longitude);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(expectedWeatherData.Name, result.Name);
            // Compare other properties as needed
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(100, -74.0060)] // Invalid latitude
        [InlineData(40.7128, 200)]  // Invalid longitude
        public async Task GetWeatherDataAsync_InvalidCoordinates_ThrowsArgumentOutOfRangeException(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockHttpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
            var weatherService = new Services.WeatherService(mockHttpClient.Object);

            // Act and Assert
            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => weatherService.GetWeatherDataAsync(latitude, longitude));
        }
    }
}


I'd consider injecting the HttpClient. And then make it a typed one, some libs like Refit can help to make that piece of cake. Then I'd prefer not to give the exact exception message out to the user. Only log it but send a more generic error. You don't want to present internals to potential attackers. About testing: what do you want to test (for)?

@Fildor thanks. I want to just test that the response is correct (i.e. the correct object is returned) when it is successful. And also when the latitude and longitude is out of range then I want to return an error

OK, so testing the input-validation, you don't really need an actual API, so you could mock it with a "NOP-Api-Client". "Correct Response" would rather be an integration test. Makes sense to test if the outside resource still is compatible with your implementation. But I would run those not as often (have been throttled before because I was totally oblivious I was "DoS"ing an API with my tests). For that test you obviously need "the real thing".
